# For line integral, how to prove $\int_L f(\vec{x})ds=\int_L f(\vec{x})dl$ while $ds$ represent arc-length and $dl$ represent chord-length?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Suppose line $L$ point $\vec{x}\in L$ and function $f(\vec{x})$ is continues on $L$.

Giving a partition of $L$ into small curves of $L_i$, the definition of line integral is $\lim_{\lambda\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta s_i$ while $s_i$ is the arc-length of small curve $L_i$ , $\lambda=\max(\Delta s_i)$ and $\vec{x}_i\in L_i$

My question is if it is sustains that $\lim_{\lambda\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta s_i=\lim_{\lambda\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta l_i$ while $\Delta l_i$ is the chord length of the small curve $L_i$.

Thanks a lot!

---

The following are my attempt:

It is known to me that  $\Delta l=\Delta s+o(\Delta s)$ while $\lim_{\Delta l\to0}\frac{o(\Delta s)}{\Delta s}=0$ Thus

\begin{aligned}
&\lim_{\lambda\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta s_i\\
=&\lim_{\lambda\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta l_i-\lim_{\lambda\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)o_i(\Delta s_i)\\
=&\lim_{\lambda\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta l_i-\lim_{\lambda\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta s_i\frac{o_i(\Delta s_i)}{\Delta s_i}\\
\end{aligned}

Therefore, my target would be $\lim_{\lambda\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta s_i\frac{o_i(\Delta s_i)}{\Delta s_i}=0$ .

However I may have difficulty with this due to the unknow sigh of $f(
\vec{x})$ .

Comment: Why does the sign of $f$ matter? All you need is that $|f|$ be bounded. Just bound by absolute values and use $o(\Delta s_i)\le \epsilon$ when $\lambda<\delta$. Don't you mean $\lim\limits_{\Delta s\to 0}\frac{o(\Delta s)}{\Delta s} = 0$? But of course if $\Delta s\to 0$, then $\Delta l\le \Delta s\ \to 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin It matters because I would like to prove that $\left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta s_i\frac{o_i(\Delta s_i)}{\Delta s_i}\right|<\epsilon$ if the function is one sigh then $\left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta s_i\frac{o_i(\Delta s_i)}{\Delta s_i}\right|<\epsilon\left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta s_i\right|$ since $\left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\vec{x}_i)\Delta s_i\right| <\infty$ thus sustains.